# Instantiating class by string

Tags: php

i have this code.

```
    $contrl = stripslashes($this->params['controller'].'Controller'); //PostController
    $obj = new $contrl(); // What's won't work
    //this don't work too
    $contrl = 'PostController';
    $obj = new $contrl();
    //but this work good
    $obj = new PostController();
```

I dont understand why it happen and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it should be done like this ([as per the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php)):

```
$obj = new $contrl;
```

Comment: I trying this too. It says  Class 'PostController' not found

Comment: Do you have the class included/required on the script your running this in?

Comment: It's `$obj = new $contrl();`.

Comment: Yes. I include file with class. I can't make instant only from string.

Comment: @user2314985 Are you sure that you're including the class properly? You may need to look into autoloading.

Comment: @user2314985 Try with just the string and no parenthesis, it's possible $contrl doesn't have the exact string you think it does in your first example.

Comment: problem was in namesapce. Sorry for disturbing.